# Rebase stream of another developer

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

Maybe this is a very basic question: I have notification that a developer has completed with his work.
But the developer hasn't rebased his stream with the recommended baseline.

Now before I want to do a "Deliver from Stream -> to default", I want to rebase his stream, which I can't do because of permission issues.
What should I do to overcome this?

Should I make an integration view in this stream to do the rebase?
Would I be then able to do "Deliver from Stream -> to default" correctly?
Merge conflicts are not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone can rebase a stream: you just need your own view on the stream you are rebasing (not on the parent stream: on the destination stream).

But a rebase isn't a deliver. You should rebase first. Then deliver.

The deliver will require the same thing: you need a view on the destination stream (here the stream to which you are delivering to)

In both cases (deliver or rebase), to avoid any permission issue, make your own view on the streams you want to change: I would recommend making a dynamic view for those operations: the rebase or deliver will complete quicker using those type of views (ie, dynamic ones).
(And speed would matter, since ClearCase is so slow, as detailed in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161514/some-questions-about-clearcase/161515#161515), and in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2012/120809-10-practices-of--highly-ineffective-software-developers.html) ;) )